# What is the git-cherry equivalent for a single missing commit?

Tags: git, patch, git-cherry

How do I check if a single commit has already been applied to a specific branch?

Using the documentation of `git-cherry` as an example:

```
       $ git log --graph --oneline --decorate --boundary origin/master...topic
       * 7654321 (origin/master) upstream tip commit
       [... snip some other commits ...]
       * cccc111 cherry-pick of C
       * aaaa111 cherry-pick of A
       [... snip a lot more that has happened ...]
       | * cccc000 (topic) commit C
       | * bbbb000 commit B
       | * aaaa000 commit A
       |/
       o 1234567 branch point

       $ git cherry origin/master topic
       - cccc000... commit C
       + bbbb000... commit B
       - aaaa000... commit A
```

How would I know that `cccc000` has the same content as `- cccc111` without having to process the whole tree? Is this possible?

Notice that `git-cherry` relies on the **patch content (diff)** and this is key to the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`git log` has a `--cherry-mark` option which adds information on symmetric differences (a.k.a "3-dots operator" `A...B`)

Try running :

```
git log --oneline --graph --boundary --cherry-mark master...topic
```

You should see unique commits prefixed with `+` (or `*` when the `--graph` option is on), and commits present on both sides prefixed with `=`.

---

If you want to know how commits are matched : `git patch-id` computes the result used by cherry-pick / rebase.

`git patch-id` expects a patch (as produced by `git show` or `git diff`) on STDIN :

```
$ git show <commit-ish> | git patch-id
<hash for patch> <hash of input revision, if it can determine a revision>
```

For example : you can view the `patch-id`s of all individual commits in `A...B` :

```
git rev-list origin/master...forkpoint | while read sha1; do
    git show $sha1 | git patch-id
done
```

You can use this result in a script, to print more explicitly how commits are linked.

Comment: LeGEC thanks for the answer! It is almost on the spot. However this still looks like we're having to compare the two branches fully, which is kind of a problem in my case (the kernel having a distant merge-base with thousands of commits being tested against each other, as one example). Do you think it is possible to do this with a single commit? If not, I'll accept this answer as is.

Comment: I think I misunderstood your initial question : you want to match the commits marked with `=` two by two ? I updated my answer.